# Need to create a button that displays a specific picture, then hides it after a specified ms duration

Tags: javascript

Not sure how to approach the task or what specific code would work but am thinking a nested function might do it.I just don't know exactly how to properly implement it.

I can create the button in HTML and have it display the picture but am unsure how to code/incorporate the setDuration (I'm assuming here) function part. Being somewhat new to JS so looking for best practices for a hopefully simple task. Sincerely appreciate any assistance/input!

Comment: You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use on click event to show picture and hide it using setTimeout.

HTML:

```
<!-- button -->
<button id="btnId">Hey Click me!</button>

<!-- image to hide and show -->
<img src="img_path_here" alt="" id="imageID" style="display: none" />
```

Javascript

```
    // add click event to button
    document.getElementById("btnId").addEventListener('click', function() {
        //show image
        document.getElementById('imageID').style.display='block';
        // hide image after 1 sec.
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('imageID').style.display='none';
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Dear Babbar, thank you sooooo much for taking the time and providing a complete answer - very much appreciated! Your code works exactly as I intended.

Answer (score 0):

Give your image an id and use:

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
    document.getElementById("id").remove();
},200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to time when your picture will disappear. It will something like this.

```
function displayPicture() {

    // code that displays picture
    image.display = "block";

    setTimeout(()=> {
    // code that hides the picture
    image.display = "none";

    // the picture will disappear in 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
}
```